# Efficiently walk up DOM tree, check nodeType and attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, recursion

Trying to think of an efficient way to check all ancestors of a given node, possibly with a TreeWalker?

Specifically, I want to see if any nodeType is `<input>` or `<textarea>`, or if `contenteditable="true"` and return true if any ancestor matches.

A recursive function is fine!

Comment: i find duck-typing to be the fastest performing. `var u; if(elm.value!=u||elm.contentEditable!=u)`... of course, SELECT and LI also define a `.value`, so you may need one more clause, but even with that, this property-sniffing pattern is faster than comparing via methods or multiple IFs. aside from that, just keep checking `elm.parentNode` until it's nothing.

Comment: yea they can, just tried in the answer section. click the textarea in dom tree, then type `$0.appendChild(document.createElement("span"))`

Comment: `input` and `textarea` are not node types (won't ever be returned as `nodeType` value), they are element names. So you would actually need to confirm if the `Node` was of `nodeType` `ELEMENT_NODE`, then fetch the `Element` object, then check the `Element.localName`.

Comment: right, i didn't realize it's `.nodeName` all this range, selection, textNode stuff is confusing me

Comment: Consider using `document.evaluate`.

Comment: @torazaburo the simplest example is when a `textNode` is descendant of a textarea, as in the answer section of this page. i definitely don't know what the limits are though. just click the `<textarea>` in the dom and type `$0.firstChild`

Comment: A `TreeWalker` with a filter should be perfectly fine. Have you tried using one?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple iterative tree climb to achieve the desired result.

```
function findParentNodes(node) {
  var parent = node.parentNode;
  while(parent) {
    if( parent.nodeName === 'INPUT' || 
        parent.nodeName === 'TEXTAREA' || 
        parent.getAttribute('contenteditable') === 'true') {

        return true;
    }

    parent = parent.parentNode;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: this is wrong because contentEditable needs to be a string `"true"`

Comment: Why not simply use the `contentEditable` property: `parent.contentEditable === true` would return a Boolean `true` or `false`; as the *attribute* may return `"true"` (as a String), but the property will return a Boolean. See (ridiculously simple) [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/edsq9ugp/) (in the console).